# JQuery use variable by name of divID

Tags: jquery, variables

Just a quick question, that I cannot fathom out, hope you guys and girls can help.

I have a `div` (with ID) that when clicked opens a new `div` - great works well, what I really want is to "populate" the new `div` with predefined text based on the clicked div's ID. example:

```
<div class="infobox" id="help_msg1">Click me</div>
```

I may have say 3 (actually more but...) of these div's

This opens:

```
<div id="helpbox">text in here</div>
```

In/on my `.js` page I have doc ready etc then:

var help_msg1 ='text that is a help message';
var help_msg2 ='text that is another help message';
var help_msg3 ='text that is yet another help message';

Then

```
$('.infobox').live('click',function() {
 $('#helpbox').remove();
 $('label').css({'font-weight': '400'});
 $(this).next('label').css({'font-weight': '900'});
 var offset = $(this).next().next().offset();
 var offsetby = $(this).next().next().width();
 var leftitby = offset.left+offsetby+10;
```

$('body').append('text in here');
 $('#helpbox').css( { 'left': leftitby, 'top': offset.top } );
 });

Note I remove each `#helpbox` before appending the new one and the `.next().next()` identifies the appropriate text input   that lot all works.

What I need is how do I put `var help_msg1` into the append when `id="help_msg1"` is clicked or `var help_msg2` when `id="help_msg2"` is clicked etc.  I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to associate your help messages with the `<div>` elements themselves using jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) facility:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#help_msg1").data("help_msg", "text that is a help message");
    $("#help_msg2").data("help_msg", "text that is another help message");
    // etc...
});
```

Then later you can fetch the message directly from the clicked `<div>` element:

```
$(".infobox").live("click", function() {
    // ...
    $("body").append($(this).data("help_msg"));
});
```

Comment: and @Scorpi0 - I learn something new from your guys & girls every day.  For someone "new" to Jquery/Java it is so like php with many different ways of attacking the same problem, most are "not wrong" just some are better than others i.e. efficient etc. I like this .data function but I need to read up a bit more before I can implement it properly - I'm just learning JQ.

Answer (score 1):

Define an array mapping elements ids to messages.

```
var messages = new Array;
messages['help_msg1'] = 'text that is a help message';
```

etc...

Then, modify your click handler to include this in order to decide what text to append:

```
var id = $(this)[0].id;
if(typeof(messages[id]) != 'undefined'){
     $('body').append(messages[id]);
}else{
     alert('no message for id '+id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, a few mods (well prob. more my basic style of writing JQuery functions :-) ) and works ok.  Thanks again

Comment: JavaScript `Array` only supports numeric keys. When you add a property with a string key like this, what you get is an `Array` whose `length` does not match the total of all its contents and members. If you're using string keys, you should use an `Object` (and you can create them with the literal syntax: `{}` for `Object` and `[]` for `Array`).

Comment: @eyelidlessness - not quite sure what you mean (I'm only learning) but I think I get it and that is what I meant by a "few mods".  Works well this way var id = $(this).attr('id'); - $('body').append('<div id="helpbox">'+messages[id]+'</div>');

Comment: @Russell, sorry my comment was addressed to Macy. SO may have changed its notification functionality so that it notified you as well because I didn't directly prefix my comment with @Macy. I was commenting on Macy's use of `Array` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like

```
$('.infobox').live('click',function(event) {
    var text = eval(event.target.id);
    ...
}
```